# Having trouble with an interactive map

Tags: google-maps, interactive

I'm trying (and failing) to use Google's visualization code to create an interactive map. When I hover the mouse over a U.S. state, I'd like the numerical value to be formatted to include a dollar sign.

Here's my map code, could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['State', 'Dollars'],
    ['US-IL', 200],
    ['US-IN', 300],
    ['US-AL', 200],
    ['US-AZ', 800],

  ]);

  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
      document.getElementById('visualization'));
  geochart.draw(data, {width: 556, height: 347, region: "US", resolution: "provinces"});
}
```

Comment: Sorry, not very experienced.Will try again.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't figure out how to use the block quotes. still trying

Comment: Have a look in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to learn how things work over here.

Comment: thank you, i'm not much of a coder (as you can see)

Answer (score 0):

To a dollar sign to the data in the hover state, you need to tell the Geochart system to format the data with the specific prefix.  If you needed to have a percentage, you could instead add a suffix with the percentage symbol.  See Google API Docs below.

Google API Docs: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformatter

In your case, the 2 lines of code to use are:

```
// Add the prefix (and set the decimal places) 
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({prefix: '$', fractionDigits: 0});

// Apply formatter to second column
formatter.format(data, 1);
```

Thus, your code would look like this:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['State', 'Dollars'],
    ['US-IL', 200],
    ['US-IN', 300],
    ['US-AL', 200],
    ['US-AZ', 800],
  ]);


// --- Code to add --- 
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({prefix: '$', fractionDigits: 0});
formatter.format(data, 1);
// --- End of Code to add ---


  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
      document.getElementById('visualization'));
  geochart.draw(data, {width: 556, height: 347, region: "US", resolution: "provinces"});
}
```